# MySQL : search string by first alphabetic letter

Tags: mysql

Here is my MySQL table :

```
id | title
1  | Albert
2  | ali
3  | " alienor "
4  | à rebour
5  | bernard
6  | cassy
```

I would like to pick all the title "starting" with "a", including lower/uppercase, accents and ignoring all non letter caracters before the first letter.

I want as a result : 1,2,3,4

I already got the regex to get the first letter :

```
^[^[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]]).*$
```

but i do not figure out how to use it in mysql query.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Is there a problem using `regex` or `rlike` ?

```
select *
from table t
where t.title rlike '^[^[:alpha:]]*[aA].*$' ;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer,
Well your query will pick title starting with "B" or "C"

Comment: this wont pick any accentuated A :(

Actually i would like to user the "power" of like ('a' LIKE 'à' = 1) in the regex

Answer (score 0):

As an additionnal bonus question :

Can i sort my query result by title ignoring the non letter characters ?

So that

```
" alienor "
```

does not come before

```
Albert
```

only because it has some double quotes.

Cheers